# Fancybox doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, fancybox

I'm using fancybox (version: 2.1.5) to show pop ups on my site and it does not work properly, it throws an error

> undefined is not a function

Every time when I'm opening and closing fancybox. Here the screenshot: http://grab.by/A5MK

I brought it to work partially and seems it fullfil my needs. But every time when I close it, background stays gray out and **I need to click on it one more time to make it go away**.

I can't puzzle out what can cause such inconsistency. Does that affiliated with jQuery version (I have it 1.7.1) or with peculiarities of fancybox? I would like to know if someone has encountered with such problem and how can I work around that? Is it feasible to get it to work or I should use another lightbox plug in?

**Note**: site created with Wordpress CMS.

Sorry for such convoluted and long-winded specification, I have tried my best to provide all information connected with problem.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** I don't know in what extent my code can be helpful on this occasion, but anyway here is my code

```
$("a.fancybox-purchase-inline").fancybox({
    prevEffect: 'elastic',
    nextEffect: 'elastic',
    autoSize: true,
    closeBtn: true,
    afterLoad: function () {
        set_billing_state_placeholder();
        show_billing_state();
    }
});
```

Comment: do you have jquery correctly loaded before your fancybox call ?

Comment: Yes jQuery loaded before fancybox call

Comment: Open you javascript console and re-try you should see an error, paste it  here

Comment: Every time when I open or close it, in console I see following error
`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`
And beside this, when I'm trying to do something after closing fancybox (e.g. open another pop up), it throws mentioned error and does not do it, **seems to exits from that block**

Comment: at this point, you need to paste your code in your question :)

Comment: ok, I believe I haven't distracted from fancybox functional, but anyway take a look please on edit.

Comment: I have tried, but it does not change anything.

Comment: Make sure you are not loading two versions of jQuery or fancybox

Comment: Nope, I have checked, it doesn't connected with that.

Comment: Maybe a link to the actual site would help, hard to guess otherwise